# Is it possible to run sqlite query in the backgroud thread and sending an email at the UI with output of query as a TO field

Tags: android, sqlite, email, android-asynctask

I am working on an app with email sending function. The email recipients address list is from an SQLite query from a database. Apparently I have to run database query in the background in order to get the email function work (see my code below). However, I don't know how to get the output of my query that contains an email list and load on to a 'TO' recipients field. The Email 'TO' field should be a string array list. The current code is not working. Could someone help me on this? Maybe there are other ways to solve my problem. I am very new to Android and Java. Many thanks!

my activity codes are here:

```
package jhapps.com.demographics;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class PromotionEmailMonthTop10 extends Activity {
private EditText subjectGroupTop10,bodyGroupTop10;
private Button  btnMonthTop10;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_promotion_email_month_top10);


    subjectGroupTop10=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.subjectMonthTop10);
    bodyGroupTop10=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.bodyMonthTop10);
    btnMonthTop10=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnMonthTop10);
    btnMonthTop10.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EmailMonthTop10();

            // after sending the email, clear the fields
            subjectGroupTop10.setText("");
            bodyGroupTop10.setText("");
        }


    });


}

//get month top 10 email list
protected void EmailMonthTop10() {

   /** DataBaseHelper dataBaseHelper=new DataBaseHelper(this);
    String[] emailGroupTop10=new String[dataBaseHelper.eMailListMonthTop10().size()];
    for(int i=0;i<dataBaseHelper.eMailListMonthTop10().size();i++){
        emailGroupTop10[i]=dataBaseHelper.eMailListMonthTop10().get(i);
    }
*/
    new  SendEmailTop10Task().execute();

    String subjects=subjectGroupTop10.getText().toString();
    String bodytext=bodyGroupTop10.getText().toString();

    //start email intent

            Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);

            // prompts email clients only
    email.setType("message/rfc822");
    email.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));


    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new SendEmailTop10Task().execute());
    //   email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String []{"junrudeng@gmail.com","huangji8@gmail.com"});

            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subjects);

            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, bodytext);
            try {
                // the user can choose the email client

                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an email client from..."));
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {

                Toast.makeText(PromotionEmailMonthTop10.this, "No email client installed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }



        }

class SendEmailTop10Task extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    // This is called on a seperate thread
    @Override
    protected Void  doInBackground(Void... Voids) {
        DataBaseHelper dataBaseHelper=new DataBaseHelper(PromotionEmailMonthTop10.this);
        String[] emailGroupTop10=new String[dataBaseHelper.eMailListMonthTop10().size()];
        for(int i=0;i<dataBaseHelper.eMailListMonthTop10().size();i++){
            emailGroupTop10[i]=dataBaseHelper.eMailListMonthTop10().get(i);
        }
     return null;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: You want to send an email between different classes of your app?

Comment: I'm not sure where to begin... The idea is that you should start your query on your onClick, with a callback for when you get your database answer. That callback will start the e-mail Intent.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, Eenvincible. No. sending email out. The email address list is generated by querying a data from database, which is handled by databasehelper.

Comment: Thank you so much MPelletier. I am going to try tonight.

Comment: I am not sure how to create a button and get callback value into

Comment: email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emaillist); emaillist is the value I need to create from database which contains the email address list.

Answer (score 0):

this is what I can come up with:

```
 public String getEmaillist() {

      btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btneMailist);
      btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              DataBaseHelper dataBaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper(PromotionEmailMonthTop10.this);
              String[] emailGroupTop10 = new String[dataBaseHelper.eMailListMonthTop10().size()];
              for (int i = 0; i < dataBaseHelper.eMailListMonthTop10().size(); i++) {
                  emailGroupTop10[i] = dataBaseHelper.eMailListMonthTop10().get(i);
              }

          }
      });

      return null;
  }
```

then add 
        getEmaillist(); 
to onCreate

modify the original code like this:

```
 String emaillist= new String();
    emaillist=getEmaillist();
    //start email intent

    Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);

            // prompts email clients only
    email.setType("message/rfc822");
    email.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));


    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emaillist);
```

this is nor working. Please provide me more information. Many many thanks